# Two Fields on backpack Laravel in same Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have two Fields inside my view but to save is my problem this two Fields whit Pivot have same Model

```php
$this->crud->addField([
    // 1-n relationship
    'label' => "Contacts Business", // Table column heading
    'type' => "contacts",
    'name' => 'contactsbusiness', // Column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
    'entity' => 'contactsbusiness', // Method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => "name", // Foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    'idcontact' => '1',
    'model' => "App\Models\Contact", // Foreign key model
    'pivot' => true,
]);

$this->crud->addField([
    // 1-n relationship
    'label' => "Contacts IS+T", // Table column heading
    'type' => "contacts",
    'name' => 'contactsist', // Column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
    'entity' => 'contactsist', // Method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => "name", // Foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    'idcontact' => '2',
    'model' => "App\Models\Contact", // Foreign key model
    'pivot' => true,
]);
```

So when saving, only the last field is saved in my table

This are my relationship

```html
public function contactsbusiness()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Contact','applications_contacts')
    ->withPivot('application_id','contact_id')
    ->where('type_contact_id', 1)
    ->using(ContactPivot::class);
}

public function contactsist()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Contact','applications_contacts')
    ->withPivot('application_id','contact_id')
    ->where('type_contact_id', 2)
    ->using(ContactPivot::class);
}
```

Please your help is welcome!!!

Comment: I have solved my problem differently ...

If anyone needs a help with this same comment and I write the solution

Thanks for Read

Comment: I have the same issue, please write the solution